# Typescript, Enums with strings and numbers

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have an interface with

```
interface mathTest {
   mathAction: MathActionEnum;
}
```

The reason for this is that I want this property to have just one of the specific values from the enum below.

```
enum MathActionEnum {
    'byOne' = 1,
    'byTwo' = 2,
    'byFour' = 4,
    'byEight' = 8,
}
```

Assume `mathAction = 'byOne'` -> received from an API response.

**First scenario**: doing an arithmetic operation, I need the number value: `let result: number = amount / MathActionEnum[mathAction]` but I get an error:

> The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
> 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

It is a number but still I need to cast it with `Number(MathActionEnum[mathAction])` for the error to go away.

**Second scenario**: equality check, I need the string value: `if (mathAction === MathActionEnum[MathActionEnum.byOne])` but I get an error:

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types
> 'MathActionEnum' and 'string' have no overlap

Which makes sense.

I'm a bit lost, is there a way to syntax it as I expect it to be? Maybe I need to define things differently?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `MathThingEnum[MathThingEnum.byOne]` return a number?

Comment: MathThingEnum.byOne return a number -> 1, MathThingEnum[MathThingEnum.byOne] returns a string -> 'byOne'

Comment: Oops, my bad. str in my case is defined as MathThingEnum but it actually contains a string value. I will rephrase my question then. Thanks.

Comment: `MathActionEnum[mathAction]` is a string

Comment: It is, I wrote the question differently.

Comment: Dividing by string will result in error, it is expected

Comment: Please read the question again, I wrote the scenarios I need and how I implemented them, obviously in a wrong way, so I ask how to do it correctly to achieve what I need.

Comment: `let result: number = amount / mathAction`

Comment: MathActionEnum[mathAction] is a number, casting it with Number(MathActionEnum[mathAction]) makes it work, it's just without the casting, I get the error I wrote. mathAction = 'byOne' is a string so doing amount / mathAction is dividing by a string which is wrong.

Comment: `Type '"byOne"' is not assignable to type 'MathActionEnum'` so I guess that `mathAction` is `MathActionEnum.byOne`. Can you show how do you assign value to `mathAction`?

Comment: Ok so now I see that your type is invalid. You marked `mathAction` as `MathActionEnum` but in reality, it is a string. TypeScript doesn't check runtime types

Comment: I know, because at runtime it's javascript, not typescript. I wonder if there's a way to define things to make it work like I want, for now, I will go with string literals combine with enum but I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: You have to map the string into the enum `mathAction = MathActionEnum [response.mathAction]`

Comment: I did something similar (I think): mathAction: condition? MathActionEnum.byOne : response.mathAction as MathActionEnum,

Comment: Using `as` is just lying to typescript that it will be fine, but it doesn't do anything.  Should be `mathAction: condition? MathActionEnum.byOne : MathActionEnum[response.mathAction]`

Comment: Just did and got "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MathActionEnum'" :(

Comment: Now it looks like the original issue I posted here, the code works in typescript playground but in vscode, I get "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MathActionEnum'" though it actually returns a number. Weird.

Comment: `mathAction: condition? MathActionEnum.byOne : MathActionEnum[response.mathAction as keyof typeof MathActionEnum]`

Comment: I managed to reproduce the error in typescript playground as well (response.mathAction is any, not string). I wanted to write it here but you beat me to it, I tried your change and now at least the error is gone. give me a few minutes to see if the scenarios are working as expected. If so, post your comment as a solution so I can accept it.

Comment: Please post your comment as a solution so I can accept it, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript enums are absolutely NOT suitable for any sort of key-value mapping. The intent is to have a grouping of uniquely identifiable labels, but labels are where it ends. While they may indeed have a number representation under the hood, they are not intended for use as a key-value store. You will have to cast it to "extract the number", and then the type is just `number`, so you effectively defeat the purpose of enums.

For all intents and purposes, think of them like keys with no useful values:

```
const MathActionEnum = Object.freeze({
  byOne: Symbol(),
  byTwo: Symbol(),
  byFour: Symbol(),
  byEight: Symbol(),
})
```

Consider the newer alternative, [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), instead. They'll provide you with type safety on both keys and values:

```
const MathActions = {
  'byOne': 1,
  'byTwo': 2,
  'byFour': 4,
  'byEight': 8,
} as const

type MathAction = keyof typeof MathActions

type MathActionValue = typeof MathActions[MathAction]
```

You get full type safety on both keys and values:

```
const example = (action: MathAction) => {
    return 2 * MathActions[action]
}

example('byOne')

// compile error, not a valid key
example('foo')

 // -------------
const example2 = (actionValue: MathActionValue) => {
    return 2 * actionValue
}

example2(4)

// compile error, not a valid value
example2(19)
```

You can even add type assertions to check if arbitrary values are a key or value:

```
const isAction = (action: string): action is MathAction => {
    return Object.keys(MathActions).includes(action)
}
isAction

const isActionValue = (actionValue: number): actionValue is MathActionValue => {
    return Object.values(MathActions).includes(actionValue as any)
}
```

You'll even get IDE autocompletion for both keys and values:

[image]

Here's a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgQygCwILCgS3BGBeGAbwCgYYByAIwE8B5MAU3IC4YBGAGlIpoBUB3ECxgAmLmSrUAYiACuAJ2EAWcT2oBRTAHNkUYQA4uAXxgJcoSFGJRqABwbwkaDNjD4YAawbUQAMxg29n6OKOhYONZ2DoihLuAAaggANrIOBIEMwTHO4ZAA2tlhrgC6xMQW0DAMAB4IALa2SWkwABQIcWCshR0AlPgAfETcZPIMUApuIjAAVCE5rhB57bmlRmUA9OswAJIAIuow-JhJSTDICABuDgiyUCCgDU1QDhCytrYg8lY19Y0MLZJ6Ewehstg9bMcHAx5PJPhwYGAQLAEDALslMAATTzeYg-R7-ci%20EBCEGkTYwAC0VOpNOp5RwsDxfymBDaHUSKQYXScRQSyVSfTwgxIZBGYwmohmpnZ-IYxDWxHJewORxOZ0u11u9xA%20OeMFe70%2031q%20JELSUpPJ4MhVRhcIRSNMqPRWLRnNxJuZLTYAE5LVtaYGg7SyhVYJgILy3Kzlq5WLIwB5EfwwD1WLHwDAI3MowMhqKYKNxvI3LRKAArBgYAB0XmoEBa3VyEB61cwYGAKQxDAbGbcZlMYGoILW5Kg8lS9MgICa1aSIC0LQARBGowCaDIFOQekv4auOuvpHJFD0QeTfMkIHKKjOGHOF8v97kAUSSbus5GD4TidvSWGP1GHKpO4bK5EBXIwAmSYgCmabSmBsofjmMqcnmIqikWEplpWNZuqkDZNgsrbtp2sjdr2KHAQOCBDiOirrOOk43rO86Liun4IZy5o7nuHGuOB3FnusF5JFeU4QLe95sU%20-Gyt6frvjJfJcb6p5AA)

Comment: I understand your approach but assuming I achieved what I need using enums, how this is different/better than using enums?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. This is statically type-safe. There's no way to use enums for this that is. You'll have to use a type assertion _somewhere_, which is means the type checker can't help you prevent errors. BTW `Number(value)` is NOT a cast, it's a parse.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsghgFwBYEEDGCCWB7EBRcaAbwCgooByAIwE8B5EYCqAXigEYAaMy2gFQDu2ZmwoVu5ajQBi2MACcRlAGZzFE3jTyYA5kgRKKADnEkAviRJpcAZwRQAbnAA2YYDdZRS5Wg2AAuKAA5SCpgeQAKeGR0LFwCSAA6X0YASg1+IUCQiDDI6NQMHHxCZJpBbHSeWlkFbNDwqMRCuJKkmrUqny1dfXrcxoLY4oSIMu09BCqLK1tsZ2BE52wdCKdXd1TLIA

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear with my question in my previous comment: Eventually I managed to achieve what I want using an enum (see my comments with Konrad above) so I wonder what advantage I will have with the const assertion.

Comment: You didn't achieve it in a typesafe manner. Konrad's comment about `as` is true. It's just lying to the compiler. But then his next comment uses `as`. Here you get no type errors, just an unexpected `NaN`:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsghgFwBYEEDGCCWB7EBRcaAbwCgpyoByAIwE8B5EYSqAXigEYAaMim2gCoB3bC3YAmHhSp0AYtjAAnMVAAsUvnTyYA5kgQqAHDwC+JEmlwBnBFEXArAB2vA2UUtIiJUGHCABcVFbYEMDImCA6eAA2VswkZhbWtpYgACaYWLhuAGZwscDmqTZQXsjoWSBuqRmVvOQA-LDeFX4EkAB0dIyF0oHw5b647RAA2vZOLh1lPpVQcFZQANbAtNg5UAi0jsDrzYOVIwC6RclQhG7iUABUpS1DIKcgwdHAHdHYOgAUhACUQA

Comment: I will try this later today and update here, thanks!

Comment: Nice idea but I can't do let action: keyof typeof MathActions = MathActions.byTwo because MathActions.byTwo is a number (2) while action is a string (one of the object's keys). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, I made two types above, one for the keys, and one for the values. If you hover over those in the playground, you'll see they're inferred as the union of all keys or values, respectively. Those aliases are definitely nicer than their expanded counterparts. If you're assigning a constant, though, there's no need for the type annotation. Generally, anything calling the code you're building will use the human-readable keys, so it's unlikely that you'll need a type alias for the numeric values at all. E.g. `const multiply = (num: number, action: MathAction) => num * MathActions[action]`

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not expose the right enum type (solved this by workaround)
It simply filters non-numeric values out.

```js
Object.values(yourTsEnum).filter((item : any) => /^([0-9]*)$/i.test(String(item))).map(item => Number(item))
```